# Save payment for later option, Stripe, React Native, Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup a way to setup a payment for later with a prebuilt Stripe component in a React Native Expo Project.

I'm following along with this project: https://snack.expo.dev/@charliecruzan/stripe-react-native-example?platform=mydevice

If you go to `PaymentsUICustomScreen.tsx`, you can see that there is an option to save payments for later when the option is rendered on the screen.
[image]

When I implement the same code, I do not get that same option.

I'm using the `useStripe` function.

This is the flow:

```
import { useStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native'
...
    const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet } = useStripe();
...
await initPaymentSheet({
    customerId: 'customerID',
    // customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey,
    paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
    customFlow: false,
    merchantDisplayName: 'Example Inc.',
    applePay: true,
    merchantCountryCode: 'US',
    style: 'alwaysDark',
    googlePay: true,
    testEnv: true,
});
```

My question is, why do I not get the save payment methods for later option?

Comment: Does the option appear if you [set `setup_future_usage` on the Payment Intent when you create it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage)?

Comment: Is you STRIP functionality working ? Can I reach you via email, I am in process of integrating STRIP with JSX but there are some integration points I dont have..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ephemeralKeys in your Frontend and as well as in your backend so that after successful payment of the user, the payment details such as card details will be saved securely in stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `clientSecret` inside the function `presentPaymentSheet` as an object property, like this:

```
const openPaymentSheet = async () => {
    if (!clientSecret) {
      return;
    }
    setLoadng(true);
    const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet({
      clientSecret,
    });

    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Success', 'The payment was confirmed successfully');
    }
    setPaymentSheetEnabled(false);
    setLoadng(false);
  };
```

Here, `clientSecret` is also a `paymentIntent`. For details, check how it was used in your example project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving payment for later you should be passing `setupIntentClientSecret` not `paymentIntentClientSecret`

```
await initPaymentSheet({
    ...
    // paymentIntentClientSecret: clientSecret,
    setupIntentClientSecret: setupIntent,
    ...
});
```